# Chaining dojo Deferred

Tags: javascript, dojo, deferred

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around chaining functions with "then" and Deferred objects.

I would like to have multiple functions (processes) chained together so that after one function with Async call is completely done, the other starts, and so on.

Something like:

```js
process1().then(process2()).then(process3());
```

I've followed many different tutorials that do it differently but i'm still not able to get a working example.

What am I missing?

Here is a [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/8xd7z429/)

Comment: Honestly, I'm just trying to learn this technique. I'm currently running process1 then i'll run process2 on its call back and so on. This works fine, but thought Deferred might be the way people are doing it these days. Hopefully I'm not trying to force a methodology that doesn't apply or should not be used.

Comment: if you are using dojo you will have trouble a lot... with everything. If you can, switch to some other technology. Dojo is horrible.

Comment: In short, make sure that function(s) are passed to `.then()` - `process1().then(process2).then(process3);`. Only where `fn()` returns a function would you write `.then(fn())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the require part (`require(["dojo/Deferred"]`) ,modern dojo use [`AMD`](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/) loading to load required modules, make reference in callback function that you'll use in your code .

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/sju1sLrq/)

In the above fiddle I've select dojo as lib and add some coniguration as the below picture

[image: dojo conifg in jsfiddle]

Snippet below :

```js
require(["dojo/Deferred",],function(Deferred){
 function process1() {
      var dfd = new Deferred();

      // perform some async logic; resolve the promise
      setTimeout(function () {
          $("#output").html("process 1 complete");
          dfd.resolve("process 1 complete");
      }, 1000);

      return dfd.promise;
  }
 
  function process2() {
      var dfd = new Deferred();

      // perform some async logic; resolve the promise
      setTimeout(function () {
          $("#output").html("process 2 complete");
          dfd.resolve("process 2 complete");
      }, 1000);

      return dfd.promise;
  }
  
  process1().then(function (){
    return process2();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">Start</div>
```

**Also, note that you can make multiple chaining as demonstrated in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/sju1sLrq/1/)**